# How to create bundle(.aab) to publish app?

Tags: android, publish

I make a App.I created its bundle to publish.This is my first time to publish a app.

I google so that i don't mess up with my first publish.i Find this

https://medium.com/@AndreSand/android-app-bundle-96ac16b36875

it say to add this code to gradle file

```
bundle {
    language {
        enableSplit = true
    }
    density {
        enableSplit = true
    }
    abi {
        enableSplit = true
    }
}
```

Now I am confused should i add this code and rebuild my bundle or my simple build bundle is enough to publish app.Is there any benefit to add this code to project? I am looking for the best way to build bundles so that i don't mess up with publish.

Answer (score 1):

I've published apps with App Bundles and never added such code to my Gradle files. I'd say just use the default settings unless you have a good reason to customize them.

Just do `Build` -> `Generate Signed Bundle / APK`, and select `Android App Bundle`.

Comment: Thank You very Much